# By Left Shifting, can 1 be set to Zero

Tags: c++, c, binary, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

I have a confused in Left Shift Operator with 1

```
int a =1;
cout<<"size of int: "<<sizeof(int)<<endl;
cout <<(a<<31)<<endl;
cout <<(a<<32)<<endl;
```

It's result:

`size of int: 4 -2147483648 1`

It prints 1 if I shift left 32 or 33.
How and why it's 1 and if I want to left shift 1 to be zero, how can I do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

It is not allowed to shift a bit value of 1 into the sign bit of a signed integer.  Doing so is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  The compiler is not guaranteed to produce any particular result if you do this.

Similarly, shifting by an amount greater than or equal to the bit width of the integer in question, whether signed or unsigned, also invokes undefined behavior.

Section 6.5.7 paragraphs 2 and 3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding the bitwise shift operators state:

*3* The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands.  The type of the result is that  of  the  promoted  left  operand.   **If  the  value  of  the  right  operand  is  negative  or  is greater than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.**

*4* The  result  of `E1 << E2` is `E1` left-shifted `E2` bit  positions;  vacated  bits  are  filled  with zeros.  If `E1` has  an  unsigned  type,  the  value  of  the  result  is *E1×2<sup>E2</sup>*, reduced  modulo one  more  than  the  maximum  value  representable  in  the  result  type.  **If `E1` has  a  signed type  and  nonnegative  value,  and *E1×2<sup>E2</sup>* is  representable  in  the  result  type,  then  that  is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

Comment: thanks for your useful answer! However,when you said " shifting by an amount greater than or equal to the bit width of the integer in question" I have another confused, if amount equal 1 (totally 1 < 32 with int type) I have a: int a= 2^32 -1; (It means 1000..00000 thirty-one zeros after the number 1), then I shift it left 1. This is not undefined_behavior, and I will get 0, I know I am wrong because its result is 2. Can you explain more?

Comment: @Anhken It *is* undefined behavior, because you are left-shifting a negative number.  One of the ways UB can manifest itself it that things appear to work as expected.  But again, there is no guarantee of that.  You can make a seemingly unrelated change and all of a sudden you get a different result.

Comment: I have one more stupid question, The same int a = a^32-1 if I shift instead of 1 I shift left 2 (to avoid a negative number) Is it still undefined behavior? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @Anhken It's already a negative number to start.  Shifting by a different amount doesn't change that.

Comment: Oh, so I know my problem, I do not have enough knowledge of the negative number as you said. Can you give me some links to learn what you say about a negative number in the binary system ?

Comment: @Anhken https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement